# Returning a value from a python script to a webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, wysiwyg

I'm working on my first website built in WYSIWYG . Let's assume there is a file called script.py which returns the value "hello".
I  have a button on my website, which when pressed should  run the script.py display the value it returns (in this case, it's hello).

Please tell me what methods do I have to use for my server to run the script and return it to the webpage.

Thanks

I tried using flask framework, that would make my problem a lot more easier, but I am a newbie to that framework so I thought it would be difficult once it is commercialised (ie, ad placements)

Comment: This question is much too broad.  It sounds like you need to work through a tutorial on the website framework software you're using.

Comment: Yes this will be a lot faster by learning `Flask/HTML/JavaScript/AJAX`
all by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Will be a lot faster than learning `Flask/HTML/JavaScript/AJAX`
all by yourself

Try doing [This](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=147813)
OR
using [This](https://github.com/dddomodossola/remi)